# Date time to Date in Knockout.JS?

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, knockout.js

While I am saving date to DataBase from my textbox it is saving as datetime I.e 
**2014-06-03T00:00:00** .

So here comes the issue I want this thing to be cut short and display just the date part in my textbox on my load I.e **2014-06-03**

I tried an alternative by declaring Model property as string instead of datetime like

```
public string CompletionDate {get;set;}
```

In my controller while saving/displaying and also while Loading is am converting and saving/displaying

`convert.ToDateTime("2014-06-03").tostring("dd/MM/yyyy");` // this works sometimes and wont sometime I.e I get a convertion issue . I can take a chance and I can't rely on this . So I am looking for out and out different feasible approach .

**My cshtml :**

```
 <input  type="text" data-bind="value:$data.CompletionDate  />
```

Here in data-bind I am getting "2014-06-03T00:00:00" instead I need to get "2014-06-03" . Any workaround is appreciated .

PS: I attached datepicker to textbox when I select date I get only date . The issue is coming while loading my page I.e data from DB

Comment: try moment.js for date conversions.

Comment: ya i looked into that before . i cant use a js file for just one simple convertion . looking something cool inside knockoutjs :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write custom function to convert date in desired format.

```
  function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date || Date.now()),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

   return [year, month,day ].join('-');
 }
 console.log(formatDate('2014-06-03T00:00:00'));
```

This function you can call directly inside binding.

```
    <input  type="text" data-bind="value:formatDate($data.CompletionDate())"  />
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmR9V/3/)

**Custom Binding**

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.datetime = {
   update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
     var value = valueAccessor();
     var newValueAccessor = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
     var d = new Date(newValueAccessor);
     if (newValueAccessor != null) {
         var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
             day = '' + d.getDate(),
             year = d.getFullYear();

         if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
         if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
         $(element).text([year, month, day].join('-'));
     }else{
     console.log("invalid date format");
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: Message: ReferenceError: 'formatDate' is undefined;

Comment: `self.myDate = ko.observable(new Date());` in place of that i need to pass my $data.CompletionDate .. which throws an error .

Comment: if CompletionDate is observable then use binding like this <input  type="text" data-bind="value:formatDate($data.CompletionDate())"  />

else remove parenthesis of CompletionDate.

Comment: what ever formatDate is undefined becoz of inplace of function call custom bindings from data-bind we need to write some logic which uses you functioning code :) looking into it . cheers

Comment: I have added custom binding. please check updated fiddle demo

Comment: `ko.unwrap(value);` error at this place .. tried unwrapable no luck

Comment: use ko.utils.unwrapObservable as unwrap doesn't work older versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55514/discussion-between-akhlesh-and-super-cool).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and used this custom binding to format the date for display:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatDate = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var newValueAccessor = ko.unwrap(value);
        var dt = new Date(newValueAccessor);
        if (newValueAccessor != null)
            $(element).text(dt.toLocaleDateString());
    }
};
```

To use it with cshtml, you just specify the name of your custom binding when you bind it.

Instead of doing the regular text binding:

```
<div data-bind="text: yourDate"></div>
```

You would specify the name of your custom binding:

```
<div data-bind="formatDate: yourDate"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/wrathchild77/JwRV7/

To bind to the value element the custom binding is a little different because you have to update the val() property of the element and not the text property. Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/wrathchild77/JwRV7/4/

And here is the code formatted for the date format you asked for:

```
/Custom Binding to the value of the element
              ko.bindingHandlers.formatDateValue = {
                  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                      var value = valueAccessor();
                      var newValueAccessor = ko.unwrap(value);
                      var dt = new Date(newValueAccessor);
                      if (newValueAccessor !== null) $(element).val(dt.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2));
                  }
              };
```

Comment: no luck mate error at unwrap (tried alternatives to this but no luck). i debugged i find empty string coming to valueaccessor in the code

Comment: Updated the fiddle to show how to update the val property, see if this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wrathchild77/JwRV7/3/

Comment: i will let you know and what if i am to post the date after edit ? i dont have any property to do so . i cant use `value:$data.completiondate` . how to use custom for display and later send the entered value ? cheers . please help me on this

Comment: This custom binding does not change the value of the observable in knockout, it just formats it for display. If you use value: it uses the build in knockout binding for value types, to get it to show up the way you want you will have to use the custom binding that you create as in the example.

Comment: yeah thats what happening here . but when i click on textbox with custom binding applied i get a datepicker when i slelect date the date is not going to controller on save i.e binding is not correct . how to make this issue go mate . which one to use ?

Comment: `<input type="text" data-bind="formatDate:$data.CompletionDate,datePicker:true" />` .. can you correct it ? value property not working ? how to send date . only my previous appeared date is going not updated one . cheers
`

Comment: Can you create a fiddler that recreates the problem so that I have something to look at to debug?

Comment: well thats so sweet of you . you can look at this post . fiddler attached . looks very simple but i am unable to apply property . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202231/issue-with-textbox-data-bind-in-knockout-fiddle-provided?noredirect=1#comment37369017_24202231 . cheers

Comment: When you submit your date, do you need it to be in the json date format, i.e 2014-06-03T00:00:00? For the submit you won't use the customBinding logic, you will have to format it using a regular function inside of your knockout model. Also, i've fixed a bug in the fiddler for that date formatter and updated the link to it in the answer. It was not applying the users location offset.

Comment: well for me display should be date . In my database column Type is datetime although you save date from UI it take zeros at end of date and store (I am not bothered what it stores in db i just need to have perfect display of date and the selected date should go back not the previous appearing one in my case ).

Comment: mate you rightly method i have to use custom binding rather using regular text or value binding . But this works super for DISPLAY but if i change my selection from 1/1/2010 (on load) to 2/2/2012 on my submit 2/2/2012 should go back to controller and save Which is not happening in my case i am getting 1/1/2010 as observable is not refreshed rightly you mentioned on Top . I am just wanna know any alternative ? cheers

Comment: see from what i observed and tried is when i use `value:$data.CompletionDate` apart from DISPLAY (i get datetime displayed ) when i select new  date(via new datepicker) in textbox on my submit selected new date going back to controller not old one which is displayed onload becoz `value` binding for textbox rightly serving its purpose . Where when i use custom binding apart from display i dont think we are sending the updated textbox content back ? i cant find any sort of binding declared ? cheers . hope you make something out of this

Comment: Checked your fiddle you are tyring to display thats cool,  can you do  improvise things a bit . what i need is on load you are showing some date in textbox . keep a button and i want on click of button i need to show the whats there in textbox using alert . Note: When i change also on click the alert content should get updated :) cheers . idea on this i can move things forward

Answer (score 1):

Use moment.js just return it is a DateTime and apply it like so:

```
<input  type="text" data-bind="value: moment($data.CompletionDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')"  />
```

[Reference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

**Edit**

Observing you want a knockout only method consider the following:

```
<input  type="text" data-bind="datetime: $data.CompletionDate, pattern: 'yyyy-mm-dd'"  />
//paste this gist somewhere prior (forgot i had the toStringFormat extension: https://gist.github.com/wbennett/707f9def34513ba7a31a)
//but its the same idea
<script>
   ko.bindingHandlers.datetime = {
    update: function(el, value, bindings, model) {
       var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value());
       var pattern = bindings.pattern || 'yyyy-mm-dd';
       $(el).text(unwrapped.toStringFormat(pattern));
    }
   }
</script>
```

[Creating custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) (from knockoutjs.com)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEdPy/1/)

Comment: i'm looking without moment.js .. yes we can do with moment.js i agree but sadly i can't use that

Comment: no luck syntax errors :( braces position is the cause

Comment: I misspelled function, did you check out the create custom bindings link?

Comment: i'm looking into the link provided . still the issue exists

Comment: @supercool Try it now, I had a comma between wrapped and toString instead of a period.

Comment: appreciated your effort . now no error likely no data :( . .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55512/discussion-between-wbennett-and-super-cool).