# Issue with TextBox Data-bind in Knockout( fiddle provided) critical one

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, calendar

**Step 1:** OnLoad of my page i am using custom bindings to show date in my textbox .

**Step 2:** The problem comes here is when i am trying to post what i have in textbox i'm getting minimum date at my controller which is wrong  i.e **{01-01-0001 00:00:00}**

My cshtml :

```
<input type="text" data-bind="formatDate:$data.CompletionDate,datePicker:true",value:'$data.CompletionDate' />
```

//formatdate is my custom binding to display formated date

Well what i am looking for is, **Is there any way we can custom bind on load and post entered data .**

Fiddle provided : http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/18/

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: some code / your viewmodel would be useful to show how you store and submit the value to your controller

Comment: you can check the fiddle . complete code provided sadly i can't reproduce my excat case but it will help you with my view model look and save sort of things .

Comment: In additional my server model date is of datetime tye . aany additional info required let me know

Comment: With the fiddle, you have txtCountryCode bound to the date value. The main thing you need to add is your ajax call, and how you are preparing the date, if you are, before sending it over.

Comment: updated fiddle you can check(comments provided where i'm stuck) . well i am not getting selected DATE to script(where my logic , ajax calls etc ) . problem is with binding  .How to send selction keeping custom binding inatct :) hope you got that