# Month-year to dd/mm/yyyy convertion issue?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datepicker

When i select a date from my date-picker i made it to display in month-year format which looks like **july 2014** .

Well i must need to convert this format to dd/mm/yyyy or whatever it may be but when i pass in **new Date()** it should be valid .

*My date-picker binding code for getting month year*

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enddate = {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                $(element).datepicker(value);
            }
            else {
                $(element).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'MM yy',

                    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {

                        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    }

                })
            }
        }
    };
```

Let me justify things i am doing  here . i need the Date should be in  `Date()` understandable format because i will pass my selected date(which will be in observable) when i select from customised Datepicker .

**Senario 1:** var dateformat= new Date("dd/mm/yyy") --> which will work fine

**Senario 2:** var dateformat= new Date("july 2014") --> Invalid date so i intend to convert to dd/mm/yyyy and do further

Comment: Convert your month/year strings to JS date object using: `new Date("1 " + month + " " + year)`

Comment: Or even `new Date(month + " 1 " + year)`.

Comment: well how to dynamically separate month and year if i have `july 2014` as my input ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs for dealing with dates. Its amazing library to work with dates.

you can use like below

var myDate = moment($(element).datepicker('getDate')).format('DD/MM/YYYY')

[Check this out](http://momentjs.com/).

```
in viewmodel you can do something like : 

self.formattedStartDate = ko.computed(function(){
 return moment(self.startdate()).format('MM/DD/YYYY);
)

});
```

Now use formattedStartDate for data-bind  or even simpler is this :

```
self.startdate( moment(self.startdate()).format('MM/DD/YYYY') )
```

Comment: well i tried in my view (cshtml) for date formatting but is it possible to use moment.js without using in data-bind ?

Comment: In above mentioned scenario you had something like `$(element).datepicker('getDate')` but i need to format date which is stored in observable i.e `self.startdate()` --> holds my july 2014 .

Comment: Yes its possible , using computed member in your model. I will edit my answer for this ,mark as answer ,or vote up if it works for you.

Comment: But i cant see reason why you cant use in data-bind if you already have it in self.startdate() ?

Comment: looks cool let me test it in some fiddle and let you know . cheers mate

Comment: try this too self.startdate( moment(self.startdate()).format('MM/DD/YYYY') )

Comment: `ajay` good point but the thing is if use it in data-bind when i change date the observable will not update sadly . i tried n left moment

Comment: Your datepicker input, bind startdate to that OR When you change date datepicker fires some event hook it up and change observable there.

Comment: well tried on that end too but no luck .You can check my previous post related to update observable issue . tried moment no luck later went with custom bindings . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202231/issue-with-textbox-data-bind-in-knockout-fiddle-provided-critical-one . cheers

Comment: Cool in fiddle its working http://jsfiddle.net/K5ub8/32/ Thank you buddie . i hope it works fine in my main machine on monday :) cheers

Comment: dude its not working i am getting something like `"NaN/NaN/0NaN"` any help is appreciated

Comment: yes may things for me in fiddle works but darn vs2012 it wont . i used excat momentjs file used in fiddle :( .